# Extracting second line of output in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

My batch-file is producing the output:

```
SHA1 hash of file E:/Test/test.zip:
b04f3ee8f5e43fa3b162981b50bb72fe1acabb33
CertUtil: -hashfile command completed successfully.
```

I want to use only: b04f3ee8f5e43fa3b162981b50bb72fe1acabb33.
Is it possible to extract the second line and store it in a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass argument `returnStdout: true` to the `bat` step to return output.
Then use either `String.readLines()` or a regular expression to extract the hash. Personally I would use a regular expression as it is more robust. It gives you an easy way to detect if the output is not in the expected format (e. g. when the tool changes the output in a future update).

Here is sample code for both ways:

```groovy
pipeline{
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('test') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def output = bat( returnStdout: true, script: '''\
                        @echo SHA1 hash of file E:/Test/test.zip:
                        @echo b04f3ee8f5e43fa3b162981b50bb72fe1acabb33
                        @echo CertUtil: -hashfile command completed successfully.
                        ''').trim()

                    // Variant 1: extract 2nd line
                    def hash1 = output.readLines()[1]
                    echo "hash1: $hash1"

                    // Variant 2: use regular expression to extract the hash
                    def regex = /SHA1 hash of file .*:\s*([a-f0-9]{40})/
                    def match = ( output =~ regex )
                    if( match ) {
                        def hash2 = match[0][1]
                        echo "hash2: $hash2"
                    }
                    else {
                        error "Invalid CertUtil output"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
hash1: b04f3ee8f5e43fa3b162981b50bb72fe1acabb33
hash2: b04f3ee8f5e43fa3b162981b50bb72fe1acabb33
```

Comment: Hi, It is working fine for me. But when I am passing the hash2 in curl command to upload it to artifactory it is not working.
"curl -u ${USER}:${PASS} -H 'X-Checksum-Sha1:${hash2}'-k -X PUT -T E:/test/test.zip https://artifactory-test.com/artifactory

Error: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: hash2 for class: groovy.lang.Binding
Could you please provide a solution for this.

Comment: @Vidisha This would be a new question for SO. When doing so, please add more detail, especially the pipeline code.

Comment: I guess we are confusing bash with batch ? or am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Based upon your provided output, the line you need is the only one which does not contain a `:` character. You should easily be able to exclude the lines which show that character by piping the `certutil` command output through `find.exe` with its `/V` option.

```batch-file
@"%__AppDir__%certutil.exe" -HashFile "E:\Test\test.zip"|"%__AppDir__%find.exe" /V ":"
```

To set that to a variable, you can add that command to a `For /F` loop:

```batch-file
@For /F Delims^= %%G In ('""%__AppDir__%certutil.exe" -HashFile "E:\Test\test.zip"|"%__AppDir__%find.exe" /V ":""')Do @Set "SHA1=%%G"
```

As a side note, it is my understanding that CertUtil can, depending upon the version, output the SHA1 result as twenty pairs, separated by spaces. If you're deploying your batch-file on systems which use such output, you could still get the 40 character output, by using a `For /F` loop:

```batch-file
@For /F "Tokens=1-20" %%G In ('""%__AppDir__%certutil.exe" -HashFile "E:\Test\test.zip"|"%__AppDir__%find.exe" /V ":""')Do @Set "SHA1=%%G%%H%%I%%J%%K%%L%%M%%N%%O%%P%%Q%%R%%S%%T%%U%%V%%W%%X%%Y%%Z"
```

Comment: I love that you put the full path of the commands (using %__AppDir__%) to add security to the script :)

Comment: Just be aware that I have seen reports @DefToneR, of `%__AppDir__%` not working in all scenarios, so generally I personally use ```%SystemRoot%\System32\``` as a more robust alternative.

Comment: Well I maintain a validation script repository, most of them in batch, I use %__AppDir__% a lot. Those script are running in .gov and .mil facilities for 2 years now. In a very very mixed scenarios and I never had any issue at all. (and I'm talking about windows 7, 8 8.1 servers, etc). on more than 8000+ computers I would say. so I can guarantee that %__AppDir__% works :D

Comment: @DefToneR, I personally have not had scripts not work as intended using it, but there have been instances whereby code using it has been reported back to me as having not. _(At least one of those, somewhere in this site)_. I have no issue with its use, and would certainly not ask people not to use it. In my final production scripts however, I check the value first, and if it doesn't report the expected path, I revert to the documented variable method instead.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested:

```
for /f "skip=1 tokens=* delims=" %%# in ('my command') do (
  set "second_line=%%#"
  goto :break
)
:break
echo %second_line%
```

But you'll have to change the expression in the brackets with your command which you've not gave. Mind that this will skip the empty lines.